# Is there a solution for the autodesk forge viewer error?

Tags: graphics, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge, viewer

We are using forge viewer on our website
and while testing the website using different computer for s/w research
we found an error

**About the Error**

- 3D model that is uploaded looks fine in every computer except for one
  computer
- using the exceptional computer when we checked out
  forge viewer basic setting check box(show edge) it became less cracked

we are assuming that it is either the model or the computer Grapic problem

the computer spec that had problem is as below

- CPU : I5-10500
- Memory : 8GB
- Grapic : UHD 630

[Error image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o257M.png)

[Error image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZJqJ.png)

[Original model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1nyC.png)

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, this is most likely a hardware (GPU) specific issue. Please contact the support at `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` with as much information as possible:

- large resolution screenshot of the problem (from different browsers, if possible)
- GPU stats of the problematic device (e.g., include the entire Chrome's GPU report you get from `chrome://gpu`)
- if possible, share your design file (confidentially; it would not be shared outside of Autodesk)